# PySide/Qt Menu bar disappearing when replaced

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to replace the current Menu bar of my application with a new one (for when the user switches language), but after applying the change the menubar is disappearing. The strange thing is that the changes show for a split second before disappearing.

Any ideas what is happening? The QMenu is pretty standard (File, Edit, View, etc.), and I'm just calling setMenuBar() on my main window.

```
def reset_menu(self):
    menu_bar = QtGui.QMenuBar()
    ##
    ## Code to add menus and actions to QMenuBar
    ##
    self.setMenuBar(menu_bar)
```

Comment: It seems that your new menu bar gets deleted. Show the code.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Added the code, but I've worked around it by clearing the first menubar and adding everything to that, rather then creating a new menubar from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internationalization in Qt-based apps does not require manual recreation of GUI objects. The right way to do it is described here http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/i18n.html

Comment: Oh, wish I'd noticed that before. Thanks Alex.